# MySQL not optimizing IS NULL clause from RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I am experiencing a challenging issue with optimization of `IS NULL` check for a joined table.

In the following query, you will see that I `RIGHT JOIN` the `calendar` table. The query works perfectly so long as I don't check if `calendar.time` `is null`.

```
select `teams`.`name` as `label`, `teams`.`id` as `id`, count(`teams`.`id`) as value 
from `likes` 

right join `calendar` on `calendar_id` = `calendar`.`id` 

left join `profile_team` on `likes`.`profile_id` = `profile_team`.`profile_id` 

right join `teams` on `profile_team`.`team_id` = `teams`.`id` 

where (
  `calendar`.`time` between '2015-02-14' and '2015-04-14' 
  or `calendar`.`time` is null
) 

group by `teams`.`id`;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200c0/7

---

The idea with the query is to have every row from `teams` returned, even if there are no related rows from `likes`. `likes` and `teams` are related through `likes.profile_id` through `profile_team.profile_id` and `profile_team.team_id` to `teams.id`.

[image: UML diagram]

`calendar` is joined as this contains reference points for filtering the data set by time.

---

Thank you for your help.

---

Edit: `EXPLAIN` output:

*With `IS NULL`*

```
| id | select_type |        table |   type |       possible_keys |                 key | key_len |                          ref | rows |                    Extra |
|----|-------------|--------------|--------|---------------------|---------------------|---------|------------------------------|------|--------------------------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE |        teams |  index |             PRIMARY |             PRIMARY |       4 |                       (null) |    1 |                   (null) |
|  1 |      SIMPLE | profile_team |  index | profile_team_unique | profile_team_unique |       8 |                       (null) |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |        likes |    ALL |         calendar_id |              (null) |  (null) |                       (null) |    8 |              Using where |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |     calendar | eq_ref |             PRIMARY |             PRIMARY |       4 | db_9_200c0.likes.calendar_id |    1 |              Using where |
```

*Without `IS NULL`*

```
| id | select_type |        table |   type |       possible_keys |                 key | key_len |                             ref | rows |                                                     Extra |
|----|-------------|--------------|--------|---------------------|---------------------|---------|---------------------------------|------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE |     calendar |  range |        PRIMARY,time |                time |       4 |                          (null) |    1 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |        likes |    ref |         calendar_id |         calendar_id |       5 |          db_9_200c0.calendar.id |    1 |                                                    (null) |
|  1 |      SIMPLE | profile_team |    ref | profile_team_unique | profile_team_unique |       4 |     db_9_200c0.likes.profile_id |    1 |                                  Using where; Using index |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |        teams | eq_ref |             PRIMARY |             PRIMARY |       4 | db_9_200c0.profile_team.team_id |    1 |                                               Using where |
```

Comment: The problem is that MySQL generally can't optimize `OR` conditions.

Comment: In your fiddle you have no null times in `calendar`. Why do you need `OR calendar.time IS NULL`?

Comment: @Barmar To get all rows from `teams`

Comment: @Barmar According to MySQL's `IS NULL` optimization page, it should be possible in a join case: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/is-null-optimization.html

Comment: I didn't see the second `right join` with `teams`.

Comment: I think that optimization only occurs when you're testing an indexed column in a table, not when you're testing the result of a left/right join.

Comment: @Barmar Here's a quote: "MySQL can also optimize the combination col_name = expr OR col_name IS NULL, a form that is common in resolved subqueries." and a JOIN example which is listed in optimized query section: `SELECT * FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.a=t2.a AND (t2.b=t1.b OR t2.b IS NULL);` Am I misreading?

Comment: That's testing a real column, not a synthesized column from the join, so it can use the table index.

Comment: Please provide an explain for this query. I suspect what really happens is that when you don't have IS NULL condition in the query, MySQL is able to eliminate some right/left joins and replace them with INNER JOIN. When you add IS NULL, this optimization is no longer applicable. Should be visible in explalin.

Comment: @Kostja The EXPLAIN is available in the sql fiddle. I think that provides a better overview that what can be done here. What should I look for in the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: the link to fiddle is 404. Look at rows examined

Comment: @Kostja What the... I've pasted it into the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT
    `teams`.`name` as `label`, `teams`.`id` as `id`
FROM
    `teams` 
    LEFT JOIN
    `profile_team` ON `teams`.`id` = `profile_team`.`team_id`
    LEFT JOIN
    `likes` ON `profile_team`.`profile_id` = `likes`.`profile_id`
    LEFT JOIN
    `calendar` ON `likes`.`calendar_id` = `calendar`.`id`
            AND
            `calendar`.`time` BETWEEN '2015-02-14' AND '2015-04-14'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    `teams`.`name` as `label`, `teams`.`id` as `id`
FROM
    `teams` 
    LEFT JOIN
    `profile_team` ON `teams`.`id` = `profile_team`.`team_id`
    LEFT JOIN
    `likes` ON `profile_team`.`profile_id` = `likes`.`profile_id`
    LEFT JOIN
    `calendar` ON `likes`.`calendar_id` = `calendar`.`id`
            AND
            IFNULL(`calendar`.`time`, 0) = 0
```

I can't test it right now ;).

---

**WHAT AM I DOING ?**

1. Make an order of joins based on a base table (`teams`), So I will have only `LEFT JOIN`.
2. Removing `WHERE` when I have `JOIN`s that is recommended.
3. Replacing `OR` by `UNION ALL` for a better performance.
4. Using `IFNULL` instead of `IS NULL`.